# GMail IMAP Append {Length}

Tags: c#, gmail, imap

When I try append command in C# see code:

```
private readonly string n = Environment.NewLine;
public string CreateDraft()
    {
        string output;
        string command = "MIME-Version: 1.0" + n +
                         "From: username@gmail.com" + n +
                         "To: username@gmail.com" + n +
                         "Subject: " + machineId + n +
                         "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" + n +
                         "TESTING" + n;
        output =  ReceiveResponse("$$ APPEND [Gmail]/Drafts (\\Draft) {" +      Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(command) + "}" + n);

        output += n + ReceiveResponse(command);

        return output;
    }

private string ReceiveResponse(string command)
    {
        try
        {
            if (InternetIsConnected() == true)
            {
                if (!(tcpc.Connected))
                {
                    Connect();
                }

                if (tcpc.Connected)
                {
                    dummy = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
                    ssl.Write(dummy, 0, dummy.Length);
                    ssl.Flush();

                    response = "";

                    do
                    {
                        bytes = ssl.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
                        char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)];
                        decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);

                        response += new string(chars);
                    } while (response.Contains("$$") == false && (response.Contains("+") == false));

                    return response;
                }

                return "Failure: Terminal Disconnected";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return "Failure";
    }
```

It says, BAD could not parse command. It crashes on `Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(command)`, it gets the length 162, but when I try 160, it works. GMAIL just won't agree what I count and then it stops working.

Answer (score 1):

Your command actually is wrong; you have to send the literal, then CRLF, then wait for the server to tell you to send more, then send the body.

Something like `{3}foo` is wrong, it should be `{3}\r\n`, wait for the server to tell you to go on, `foo`.

Comment: As you can see, I have a variable n, which is assigned to Environment.Newline. I use it before sending foo.

Comment: The thing is, that what people count as 3character (foo), gmail does it actual characters minus 2, then it works.

Comment: Is Environment.Newline variable depending on platform?  IMAP should ALWAYS use\r\n.

Comment: The number is the number of characters in the argument. A command ends with CRLF, ie. there's a tag, a space, the command name, some arguments, and finally CRLF. That CRLF isn't part of the literal argument, it's something you have to send after the last argument.